# python cx_Oracle query end

Tags: python, sql, oracle, cx-oracle

I'm trying to update a SQL table using Python's cx_Oracle library, but I'm getting error cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended, irrespective of the query end (with/without ;). Any ideas what may be happening?

```
UPDATE TABLE_NAME
SET ROW_NAME = 345434, ISSUE_DATE = 2020-02-03 12:14:28
WHERE ROW_ID = 327692
```

Note: the date is passed in as a datetime object. The code above is showing what is output from the stack trace.

Comment: 2020 - 02 - 03 = 2015.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have a comma at the end of issue date,
also you will need to pass the date as a string

```
UPDATE TABLE_NAME
SET ROW_NAME = 345434, 
    ISSUE_DATE = '2020-02-03 12:14:28'
WHERE ROW_ID = 327692e
```

also you can do this:

```
UPDATE TABLE_NAME
SET ROW_NAME = 345434, 
    ISSUE_DATE = to_date('2020-02-03 12:14:28', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss am')
WHERE ROW_ID = 327692e
```

let me know if this helps :-)

Comment: It's actually passed in as a datetime object (which isn't shown above). The error reads without the "," at the end of date, so I assume the date is passed correctly.

Comment: try it and find out. usually these errors come one at a time in sql. when you remove the comma from the end. you will see the rest of errors. I simply provided the best result in which you should write the query. if you are passing a variable no need to do the following just remove the comma

Comment: Removing the "," after issue date and passing in issue date as datetime object resulted in the same error. Not sure what its complaining about.

Comment: show the python code regarding how the cx_oracle is calling the cursor.execute()

Comment: Turns out you were right. Python was passing the dateTime object into the query, but rendering the dateTime as a string BEFORE passing to the oracle DB. Using to_date() as described above fixes the issue.